# How to make fields editable for the user based on the profile and object field condition?

Tags: apex, trigger

I have written the below trigger where the fields of objects need to make it as editable for the user based on the **one field of same object and profile.**

firstly I have made all the fields of the object to read only for the profile.
and then I have created the Permissionset for the fields which I want to give edit access for the user. then I wrote a trigger where it has to check 
1.field condition and 
2.need to get logged in user who is trying to create record, then need to check the profile name , then need to assign that permission set to the user.

```
trigger test on objectx(before insert)
{
if (Trigger.isBefore)
{
  if (Trigger.isInsert) 
  {
    for ( objectx x : trigger.new)
     {
      if(x.status == 'Draft')
         {
         id id1 = userinfo.getUserId();
         string pf = userinfo.getProfileId();
          if(pf=='00eG000000101pK')
        {
                 PermissionSetAssignment psa = new PermissionSetAssignment(PermissionSetId = '0PS3C0000004Fpa',AssigneeId = id1);
         insert psa; 
        }
        insert x;
         }
      }
   } 
 }        
}
```

getting error as

> line 16:7 no viable alternative at character ' '

Comment: Did you copy this code from somewhere? Try typing it out yourself. Seems like a zero width space character might have crept into your code.

Comment: Also, I strongly advise against hardcoding IDs. It's much easier to use the Profile Name, or similar.

Comment: ok I wil replace the profile id with the profile name. but can you help me y am I getting the error

Comment: One more thing you should not put **DML insert inside for loop no never**!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the strange solution of `no viable alternative at character ' '`

- Copy the code from the editor.
- Paste the code into Notepad (if OS is Windows) or in TextEdit (MacOS).
- Copy again from the notepad and paste into editor
- Click Save.

This error is coming because code is copied from any website and paste into editor most probably, it is dev console.

I was able to save the code without any issue:-
[image]

In addition you must move al hardcoded text into [Custom Labels](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/labels_value_provider_platform.htm).

Comment: Hi ashwani, I haven't copied code from anywhere. I just wrote sample in notepad then copied. as you said I copied once again from notepad and pasted in editor. still facing same issue. is this code is right?

Comment: I copied the code from you question and paste in dev console. I was able to save it. @Sayed

Comment: Thanks Ashwani. now i am able to save without error. can you please help me y I am getting the error while updating the existing record as 'Apex trigger PSA_on_WO caused an unexpected exception, contact your administrator: PSA_on_WO: execution of BeforeUpdate caused by: System.SObjectException: DML statement cannot operate on trigger.new or trigger.old: ()'

Comment: trigger PSA_on_WO on service_Order__c (before update){
    if(Trigger.isBefore)
    {
      if(Trigger.isUpdate)
      {
        for ( Service_Order__c wo : trigger.old)
   {
        if(Order_Status__c == 'Pending')
          {
           id id1 = userinfo.getUserId();
           string pf = userinfo.getProfileId();
            if(pf=='profile1')
    {
                 PermissionSetAssignment psa = new PermissionSetAssignment(PermissionSetId = '0PS3C0000004Fpa',AssigneeId = id1);
      insert psa; 
    }
        update wo;
          }
         } 
      }    }
}   @ashwani

Comment: you can not dml update insert same record which is part of trigger.new. @Sayed  only make changes dont DML

Comment: then how to make changes on existing record? is that code need any modification. please guide.

Comment: @Sayed trigger will take care of update. You need to update fields only

Comment: I am trying to update the fields through the permission set . is the above code is correct?

Comment: @Sayed you don't need to perform dml on object same as trigger. PermissionSet dml is fine.